# What is happening to instance variables referred to from within an imp_implementationWithBlock?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

For a project I'm working on, I had to dynamically provide the implementation for some dynamic properties.  While doing so, I noticed during testing that instance variables I was referring to in the imp_implementationWithBlock block would always return the value it had when I declared the block, instead of the value of the current instance variable.

ie:

- My first instance has an instance variable value of @"test1"
- Upon the first initialization, if my dynamic method does not yet exists, I create it using imp_implementationWithBlock and then class_addMethod.
- Then, if accessing the dynamic property obj1.dynProp, I get my @"test1" value back.
- I instantiate a second object with a value of @"test2".
- The dynamic property already has an implementation so I do nothing more on this front.
- Now, if I access the dynamic property obj2.dynProp, I still get the @"test1" value back.

In the end, I simply used class_getInstanceVariable to retrieve the instance variable and everything is working properly, but I'd like to understand why it wasn't working in the first place. The instance variable obviously seems to be copied along with the block inside imp_implementationWithBlock but I can't find the relevant documentation explaining exactly what is happening.

Here is a simple class that reproduces the issue :

**DRTestObject.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DRTestObject : NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)aCustomString;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString *customString;

@end
```

**DRTestObject.m**

```
#import "DRTestObject.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

/*************************************************************************************/

@interface DRTestObject()
{
    NSString *_aCustomString;
}

@end

/*************************************************************************************/

@implementation DRTestObject

@dynamic customString;

- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)aCustomString
{
    self = [self init];
    if(self){
        _aCustomString = aCustomString;
        [self addDynamicMethod];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addDynamicMethod
{
    if(![self alreadyHasImplementation]){
        IMP dynamicIMP = [self dynamicImplementation];
        class_addMethod([self class], NSSelectorFromString(@"customString"), dynamicIMP, [@"@NSString@:" UTF8String]);
    }
}

- (BOOL)alreadyHasImplementation
{
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], NSSelectorFromString(@"customString"));
    return method != NULL;
}

- (IMP)dynamicImplementation
{
    return imp_implementationWithBlock(^NSString * (id _self) {
        return _aCustomString;
    });
}

@end
```

**Test calls**

```
DRTestObject *testObj1 = [[DRTestObject alloc] initWithString:@"testObj1"];
NSLog(@"TestObj1 Custom String : %@", testObj1.customString); // Returns testObj1

DRTestObject *testObj2 = [[DRTestObject alloc] initWithString:@"testObj2"];
NSLog(@"TestObj2 Custom String : %@", testObj2.customString); // Also returns testObj1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your `-(IMP)dynamicImplementation` is same as:

```
- (IMP)dynamicImplementation {
    id blockSelf = self;
    return imp_implementationWithBlock(^NSString * (id _self) {
        return blockSelf->_aCustomString;
    });
}
```

It captures the **first** instance and returns its `_aCustomString` ivar.

You should use `_self`:

```
- (IMP)dynamicImplementation {
    return imp_implementationWithBlock(^NSString * (id _self) {
        return _self->_aCustomString;
    });
}
```

Comment: You are quite right sir.  Just so other people know, doing a _self->_aCustomString does not work if self is declared id _self.  it must be declared DRTestObject *_self